# How to unlock Lenovo hdd password

Tags: hard-drive, passwords, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo V130-15IGM laptop which I have not set an hdd password for before then it happens last week that it started asking for hdd password. What could cause this and how can I go about it?
Because I checked Lenovo support they put it there that they cannot help resetting any hdd password.

I don't care about anything data on the hdd I just want to remove the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have set the password and perhaps forgot it or do not remember setting it up.

I use Lenovo machines with BIOS and Disk passwords.

Lenovo does not set up passwords on BIOS or on the Disk on their machines. Because of this, they cannot help with passwords.

If you cannot remember the password, then you must replace the disk in the computer.

There may be a problem with the drive requiring replacement in any event.

Comment: Okay, but I don't remember setting any disk password before. And it has never prompt for hdd password before, I don't know how it happens.

Comment: There may have been something you were working on that caused this. A drive will never set a password on its own. There may be a problem with the drive.

Comment: Okay thanks that means I will opt in for a new hard drive

Comment: Okay thanks that means I will opt in for a new hard drive

Comment: Perhaps you can mark my answer as helpful then,

Comment: Try the hard drive on different devices sometimes you can access the data